# Matplotlib not plotting line between data points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of snowfall accumulation data that I am plotting from a csv that looks like so: [image: CSV Exeample]

I am attempting to plot the GFS data against the RAP data and the RAP will plot flawlessly with points and lines that connected them. However, the GFS will only plot as point data: [image: GFS vs. RAP current graphic] and I, for the life of me, have not found a way to to plot the GFS data with a line to connect that points. Here is the code that I have been working with:

```
gfs = df['GFS']
rap = df['RAP']
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
ax2.plot(fh,gfs,'ob-') 
ax2.plot(fh,rap,marker='x')
ax2.tick_params(which='major',labelsize='12')
ax2.grid(which='major', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle='-')
plt.xticks(rotation='90')
plt.xlabel('Forecast Run')
plt.ylabel('Snowfall Accumulation (in.)')
plt.legend()
```

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Edited graph with ~np.isnan():[image: Edited Graph]

Comment: You need to remove the points for which there is no data.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: I have tried removing the 'NaN' values using .ffill() and .dropna() with still the same result of plotting just points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, you can remove missing values like this:

Replace

```
ax2.plot(fh,gfs,'ob-')
```

with

```
ax2.plot(fh[~np.isnan(gfs)],gfs[~np.isnan(gfs)],'ob-')
```

**UPDATE:**

The above method likely results in changing the order of the x axis. Here is a workaround:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make up some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({"GFS": [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 
                          2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 4], 
                    "RAP": [-2.45832646,  0.56266567, -0.4453474 , 
                            -0.85447845, -1.34830127,
                            -0.38113925, -0.41400397,  
                            np.nan, -0.78764545, -0.02807674]})
fh = np.array(["Fri 4 am", "Fri 6 am","Fri 8 am","Fri 10 am",
                "Fri 6 pm","Fri 10 pm","Sat 4 am","Sat 6 am",
                "Sat 8 am","100az 10 am"
                ])
gfs = df['GFS']
rap = df['RAP']


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
# workaround to set the order of xlabels
ax2.plot(fh, [np.nan]*len(fh)) 
# remove nan's  so that the points are connected
ax2.plot(fh[~np.isnan(gfs)], gfs[~np.isnan(gfs)], "ob-") 
ax2.plot(fh[~np.isnan(rap)],rap[~np.isnan(rap)],marker='x')
ax2.tick_params(which='major',labelsize='12')
ax2.grid(which='major', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle='-')
plt.xticks(rotation='90')
plt.xlabel('Forecast Run')
plt.ylabel('Snowfall Accumulation (in.)')
```

[image]

Comment: Using the ~np.isnan() function then causes issue like the new edited graph above to the RAP data as it plots

Comment: I see. The x axis order changes when you use `~np.isnan()`. I have posted a workaround for that problem in an update.